# Strange exception raised from ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

We just observed very strange exception during the call to send a message, the stack trace looks like the following:

```
- unable to send message - Implement me. @ root cause @ := javax.jms.JMSException: Implement me.
        ...@ root cause trace := @
javax.jms.JMSException: Implement me.
at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1377)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1305)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1795)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:277)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:212)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:300)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQQueueSender.send(ActiveMQQueueSender.java:111)
......
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Implement me.
at org.fusesource.mq.leveldb.LevelDBStore.getLastProducerSequenceId(LevelDBStore.scala:367)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.getProducerBrokerExchange(TransportConnection.java:1344)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessage(TransportConnection.java:451)
at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage.visit(ActiveMQMessage.java:681)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:292)
at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:150)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:229)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport.serviceRead(NIOTransport.java:138)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport$1.onSelect(NIOTransport.java:69)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.SelectorSelection.onSelect(SelectorSelection.java:94)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.SelectorWorker$1.run(SelectorWorker.java:119)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
... 1 more
```

And it didn't happen at the first time, I mean, it would succeed in sending message at the days of running, but at some time, it just failed with these errors.

Could someone tell me what would cause this? or some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be from some problem in the LevelDB store.  That store is new and issues are expected.  You can switch to the older more robust KahaDB store by changing you activemq.xml.  If you can provide a reproducible test case then the best thing to do is to open a Jira issue at the ActiveMQ site.

Comment: I just obersvered more and found that after reconnecting(I configured fail over reconnection), the exception would arise during sending messages. And you are right, after switching to kahadb, the exception is gone.